# Laravel 5 - Set fields to nullable on table create

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

I have a multi-tenant installation and am working with creating new hosts automatically. I am trying to simply set the Allow Null value on a table for each of the columns when the table is first created. This is not working but later migration files that add new columns to the existing table to work with setting them to nullable.

I am using the following to first create the table, null not set:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('phone_logs', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('type')->nullable(true)->change();
        $table->string('groupId')->nullable(true)->change();
        $table->string('status')->nullable(true)->change();
        $table->string('status_code')->nullable(true)->change();
        $table->longText('message')->nullable(true)->change();
        $table->string('sender')->nullable(true)->change();
        $table->string('receiver')->nullable(true)->change();
        $table->string('contactNumber')->nullable(true)->change();
        $table->dateTime('date')->nullable(true)->change();
        $table->string('messageUID')->nullable(true)->change();
        $table->integer('has_read')->nullable(true)->change();
        $table->string('lists_sent')->nullable(true)->change();
        $table->string('user_id')->nullable(true)->change();
        $table->string('audio')->nullable(true)->change();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Then using this to add 3 new columns to the table and it does set null:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('phone_logs', function (Blueprint $table) {
        //
        $table->string('reply_numbers')->nullable(true);
        $table->text('auto_response_1')->nullable(true);
        $table->dateTime('schedule_date')->nullable(true);
    });
}
```

I added ->change() after reading a few suggestions and also included nullable(true) instead of just nullable() as that was suggested as well but still doesn't set and requires me to do so manually.

Comment: Are you cteating new table or changing existing table?

Comment: Creating, schema::create. Schema::table later on to add more columns using a different migration file sets nullable fine

Comment: If you're creating a new Table, you don't need to use `->change()`, since there's nothing to change :) You can simply do `$table->string('name')->nullable();` and you're good to go. Or at least you _should_ be able to do that.

Comment: That's what I was using, I added ->change() only just now after reading some other suggestions about changes after 5. Without or without it I'm not seeing a change, still Allow Null is unchecked. I also tried with using ->default('NULL') but that didn't work either.

Comment: Would you please update your question with `Schema::table ……`

Comment: Have you already run this migration? If so, you'll have to re-run the migration (via rollback or refresh, etc), and run again, or do this in a new migration. I've got plenty of migrations that have `nullable()`, then when run, produce `NULL: YES` when checking via `DESCRIBE example;` in SQL.

Comment: @sta But that's not the problem. Schema::table works fine in other migration files after the table is already created. My issue is with Schema::create as the initial creation of the table does not set the fields to nullable.

Comment: I'd try this; `php artisan make:migration CreateNullExampleTable`, then in that file, add `$table->bigIncrements('id');` and `$table->string('example')->nullable();`, then run `php artisan `migrate` and then `DESCRIBE null_example;` that should give you definitive proof of this working or not working :) `null_example.example` should be `NULL: YES` in the output.

Comment: What the error you get?

Comment: All migration files run successfully and I can log into the new host - there are no errors, but the columns on the table that were created in the initial migration file are not set to Allow Null. All columns added in later files which just add 1 or 2 new columns to the existing table work fine.

Comment: @TimLewis it's Voyager + Hyn Multi-tenant. Is runs a new migration on creating a new host + database for the new tenant. So I need to let it run then have it refresh again?

Comment: I added the schema::table example to the OP

Comment: Ah, sorry, I'm not familiar with that package, and I'm not sure if Voyager handles migrations differently that basic Laravel. But the basic idea is that if a migration has been run, editing it won't do anything until you re-run the migration. I'm not sure if that applies here or not.

Comment: I may end up just creating the id column only for the schema::create since that can't be null and then move all the other columns into the update scheme::table file since that works. But weird it's not.